Ubuntu logo doesn't apear in boot screen and stays black after upgrade to 24.04
I recently updated Ubuntu version from 23 to 24.04, then had problems with Nvidia drivers because some libraries were missing.
After a reboot the Ubuntu logo doesn't appear and, after a few seconds, it turns black. It's like there is no system to boot. I can't see any relevant error messages, the entire screen is black. I've tried to open the terminal, turn off secure boot, change UEFI to legacy support, none of them worked.


If you cannot open the terminal you will have to reinstall. Moreover, if you want to fix the graphics problem later, you will need to tell us what was the error.
